# SVG text in D3.js renders in development but not production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, d3.js

I am building a visualization using D3.js in a Rails app that is on Heroku. In my chart, I have the following text element:

```
svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 10)
    .style("font-size", "1em")
    .text(totalFunding[0].disclosed_deals + " investments with disclosed sums." );
```

The code works perfectly in development. But for some reason, the `<text>` tags display in production but the text itself doesn't. In console, I'm getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cssText' of null`. But I'm not sure if it's related to this.

I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: The error implies that there is a problem trying to set an inline style on the element (and then the error on that line prevents the text content from being set on the next line).  I don't know much about Rails/Heroku, but you could try using CSS for styles.  Or just leave it off: setting font size as 1em is somewhat irrelevant anyway -- it just says set the font size as the current font size.

Comment: hmm tried this. didn't work. thanks anyway!

Comment: Were you getting the same "cssText" error without the `.style` call?  Or was something else going wrong?

Comment: I figured it out. It was a problem with my Ruby on Rails code on the server end that failed to create the Array.